# null TableLayout when reading table from xml

Tags: android, null, tablelayout

i would like to ask something about TableLayout..

In my code i read TableLayout from xml using
 
"TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);" and then i add dynamically table rows..
I have a button for refreshing the table..So, when i press the button i use
mainLayout.removeAllViews(); for delete all views from main layout and then
"TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);" i got null as result..
Anyone knows the reason i got null when i try to read from xml for second time the table??

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Can you specify where you are getting your error?

Answer (score 1):

findViewById does not load the layout from XML.  It finds views by ID that have already been inflated, generally with a setContentView call.

In your example, you call removeAllViews, then try to find a view in the hierarchy, which naturally returns null because you just removed them.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved..
I used table.removeAllViews(); instead of mainLayout.removeAllViews();